# Can't create a stack allocated array in a class with a constant variable size

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constants

Why doesn't this code compile?

```
class MyClass
{
    const int size = 5;
    int arr[size];
};
```

The error says that `size` is undeclared identifier.

Comment: Better: `class MyClass
{
    std::array<int, 5> arr;
};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A default member initializer (the `= 5;` in your code) specifies only how the non-static data member is initialized *by default*. A constructor *could* give it a different value. As such, the compiler cannot *know* what its value will be at compile time.

And therefore, you cannot use `A::size` in a compile-time constant expression. Like when you declare an array's size.

If you intend for every `A` to have a `size` of 5, then the variable should be a `constexpr static` member. Or as suggested in a comment, a `std::array<..., 5>`.

Answer (score 4):

You need a constant expression for the size when you declare an array.

Making the size `static` would solve your problem

```
class MyClass
{
    const static int size = 5;
    int arr[size];
};
```

Generally, you would prefer `std::array` instead since the size is fixed. Optionally you could include the size as a template parameter.

```
template <std::size_t N>
class MyClass
{
    std::array<int, N> arr;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

That's because `size` is non-static, and you're trying to access that constant "statically" (without an object, that is).

Comment: What does it mean to access a constant statically?

Comment: it means you're trying to access a member without an object instance of that class.

Comment: without an object instance there is also no `arr`