# const int, member array size

Tags: c++, constants, singleton

My code basically:

```
class myclass : public singleton<myclass> {
    public:
        myclass();
    private:
        const float myfloat = 6000.0f;
        const int sz_arr = (int)myfloat;

        int arr[sz_arr];  // compiler complains about this line
};
```

Need to create `arr` at compile-time. Size of `arr` is known at compile-time! Ought to be computed based on `myfloat` value. How to achieve it? Also, `myclass` is singleton, only one instance of it is ever going to be created.

Comment: There may be better answers, but I did some searching and this answer should solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696172/cant-create-a-stack-allocated-array-in-a-class-with-a-constant-variable-size

Comment: use `static constexpr` instead of `const`

Comment: `const` in this context means the value will not be changed after a given instance is created. The constructor could, for example `myclass(): myfloat(some_variable)`. Now you don't have what the compiler considers a compile-time value.

Comment: You could improve your question slightly by ditching the `: public singleton<myclass>` since otherwise it compiles perfectly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create a stack allocated array in a class with a constant variable size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696172/cant-create-a-stack-allocated-array-in-a-class-with-a-constant-variable-size)

Comment: The problem with `static` is that `static const float` cannot be assigned value in header, therefore `sz_arr` (being `static const int`) cannot be used to create compile-time array

Comment: Unrelated Note: leaving the constructor `public` kind-of ruins the object as a singleton. Anyone can instantiate an object with a `public` constructor whether you want them to or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `sz_arr` can't be used to specify the size of the array, you need to make it `static`. And mark `myfloat` as `constexpr` to make it known at compile-time (and better for `sz_arr` too).

```
class myclass : public singleton<myclass> {
    public:
        myclass();
    private:
        constexpr static float myfloat = 6000.0f;
        constexpr static int sz_arr = myfloat; // implicit conversion is enough

        int arr[sz_arr]; 
};
```